# How to determine amount of chunks from http.get response ( Node.js )

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, encoding, chunks

I am wondering if there is a way to gather how many chunks are going to be sent back when requesting a page using http.get. My initial thought is that perhaps there is a way to determine it through the callback response before actually receiving the chunks.

Take for example:

```
http.get({
  hostname: 'io-chat.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/js',
  headers: {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36'},
}, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];
  res.on("data",function(i){chunks.push(i)});
  res.on("end",function(){console.log(chunks.length)});
})
```

on "end" I have the console print how many chunks were received I would like this information prior to receiving them all, so that the loader can know how many chunks to expect.

Furthermore, I am wondering why I am receiving what seems to be a within-range random number of chunks. Sometimes while loading this and other pages, I get a number of chunks ranging from 173 to 176. What is the reason for this, and does it really matter?

Comment: In short, that's not possible, as the number of chunks depends on the number of TCP packets it will be sent into - and that can be only approximated.

Comment: Okay, can you then at least predict the size of the data? Either in character length or file size?

Comment: Well, you can check headers for `Content-Length`, but it's up to server to set that up. In this particular case server doesn't care. )